# can spring cloud config be used to set configuration properties without needing application restart

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

can we use spring cloud config to change the configuration properties of one of the beans at runtime without having to restart the application i.e requiring context reloading.

I currently have a spring boot setup where any change to the application properties needs a restart of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options for refreshing the config properties without restart with spring cloud config. You can:

- call the refresh endpoint if you are using the spring actuators. Remember to consider the `@RefreshScope` for beans dependent on certain properties. See https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/
- use Spring Cloud Config Bus as a means of broadcasting config changes to all config clients. https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-bus#learn

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might still consider a rolling restart of your application as a simple solution depending on the capabilities of your platform and whether your app is cloud native in that it is not a stateful workload.

Comment: Also, if we use AWS for deployment. Does this mean that we would have to deploy a new jar for the cloud-config-server every time we add a new application config change

Comment: If your config is externalized from the application, you do not need to build a new artifact. Since you're using config server, the app can just fetch its most recent config on startup or on some sort of refresh event. I would advise against packaging the config with the app. Instead, have a single artifact with different deployments and allow the config that exists in each environment to be what flexes.